# GoogleMap и ViewModel

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I have a screen that contains fragment as a map

**XML**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/design_default_color_background"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_back"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/back" />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTextBlack"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <fragment
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ll_bottom"
        android:id="@+id/googleMap"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <View
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_divider"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

in OnViewCreated, I first set the map, then set the viewModel
and only then I get the bundle and set the value in the viewModel to observe the variable

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setupMap()

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), viewModelFactory).get(MapNewTwoViewModel::class.java)

        setupViewModel()
        getBundle()
    }
```

there's nothing special about SetupMap

```
private fun setupMap(){

        val fragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap) as SupportMapFragment

        fragment.getMapAsync(this)

    }

override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?) {
        googleMap = map
        googleMap?.uiSettings?.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true
        googleMap?.uiSettings?.isZoomControlsEnabled = true
        googleMap?.uiSettings?.isCompassEnabled = true
        googleMap?.let {
            setupCluster(googleMap!!)
        }
        googleMap?.setOnMapClickListener {
            if (isClient) {
                viewModel.setType(MapNewTwoViewModel.OrderType.MY)
            } else
                viewModel.setType(MapNewTwoViewModel.OrderType.ALL)

        }
    }
```

**setupCluster**

```
private fun setupCluster(map: GoogleMap) {
        clusterManager = ClusterManager(MyApplication.applicationContext(), map)

        renderer = DotRenderer()
        clusterManager?.renderer = renderer
        if(clusterManager != null){
            Log.d("ClusterManager", "true")
        } else {
            Log.d("ClusterManager", "false")
        }
        map.setOnCameraIdleListener(clusterManager)
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager)
        map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(clusterManager)


        clusterManager?.setOnClusterClickListener(this)
        clusterManager?.setOnClusterItemClickListener(this)

    }
```

in setupViewModel i just watching MediatorLiveData

```
viewModel.mediatorLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            Log.d("MediatorLiveData", it.size.toString())
            setItemsCluster(it)
        })
```

setItemsCluster required for clustering

```
private fun setItemsCluster(orders: List<OrderX>){
        //---somesthing Operation/.
        if(clusterManager == null){
            Log.d("ClusterManager", "null")
        }
        clusterManager?.addItems(itemClusters)
        clusterManager?.cluster()
    }
```

now logs:

```
2020-10-21 18:53:23.658 30104-30104/com.app D/ClusterManager: null
2020-10-21 18:53:23.722 30104-30104/com.app D/ClusterManager: true
2020-10-21 18:53:23.734 30104-30104/com.app D/OnClustersChanged: []
```

Question, why did viewModel.observe()
work faster than onMapReady?

After all, I called it later than setupMap (onMapReady, where Cluster is initialized)

And how to fix it?
For this reason, I do not add points to ClusterManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up bindings for the map after it is ready. Like so:

```
override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?) {
    ...

    setupMapBindings()
}

fun setupMapBindings() {
    viewModel.mediatorLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        setItemsCluster(it)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

getMapAsync is asynchronous (obviously by its name) and takes some time for the map to be ready, when you initially observe LiveData it will return what its current value is so that you always have a value

Comment: how do I solve the problem?  clusterManager depends on Google maps, and when liveData is triggered, I set the value. and since ClusterManager = null, I can't add points. And MediatorLiveData will no longer work if The data doesn't change. Do I need to save a value inside a Fragment? and when onMapReady is complete, call setItemsCluster?